# How to change md fab speed dial to show on click? Angular material

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, angular-material

How to change md-fab-speed-dial to open and activate the speed dial menu with click, not hover.
And how can i remove that whitespace (on the picture)?

Here is view

```
md-fab-speed-dial md-open="demo.isOpen" md-direction="{{ demo.selectedDirection }}"  ng-class="demo.selectedMode"
    md-fab-trigger.actions-icon-menu
      md-button.md-icon-button aria-label="menu"
        md-icon.more-icon md-svg-src="#{asset_path('icons/more_icon.svg')}"
    md-fab-actions.actions-menu
      section.actions_icons layout="row" layout-align="center center"
        md-button.md-primary aria-label="edit icon"
          md-icon md-svg-src="#{asset_path('actions_icons/edit.svg')}"
        md-button.md-primary aria-label="remove icon"
          md-icon md-svg-src="#{asset_path('actions_icons/remove.svg')}"
        md-button.md-primary aria-label="download icon"
          md-icon md-svg-src="#{asset_path('actions_icons/download.svg')}"
        md-button.md-primary aria-label="print icon"
          md-icon md-svg-src="#{asset_path('actions_icons/print.svg')}"
        md-button.md-primary aria-label="mail icon"
          md-icon md-svg-src="#{asset_path('actions_icons/mail.svg')}"
```

Controller:

```
function ($scope, $mdSidenav, $mdUtil, $location, Invoice) {

      $scope.demo = {
        topDirections: ['left', 'up'],
        bottomDirections: ['down', 'right'],

        isOpen: false,

        availableModes: ['md-fling', 'md-scale'],
        selectedMode: 'md-fling',

        availableDirections: ['up', 'down', 'left', 'right'],
        selectedDirection: 'left'
      };
    }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Whether `md fab dial` is open depends on 'demo.isOpen' model.
You can decide it to use `ng-mouseenter` or `ng-click`.

Answer (score 0):

Just set `md-trigger` as `click`

Eg:

```
<md-fab-speed-dial md-trigger="click" md-direction="down" class="md-scale md-fab-top-right"></<md-fab-speed-dial>
```